# Concatenação de Strings em Assembly x86

Tags: c, string, assembly, x86

Tenho de implementar uma função que concatene numa String3 apontada por ptr3 às strings apontadas por ptr1 e ptr2.
Eu faço o `main()` em C, e as funções em Assembly x86. Ao executar, *o output é `123` sendo que deveria ser `123456`*.

O meu código está como segue abaixo, dividido por arquivos:

MAIN.C

```c
//variáveis globais

char string1[] = "123";

char string2[] = "456";

char string3[] = "";

char* string1Ptr = string1;

char* string2Ptr = string2;

char* string3Ptr = string3;

int main(){

printf("String1: %s\n", string1);

printf("String2: %s\n", string2);

str_cat();

printf("String3: %s\n", string3);

return 0;
}
```

FUNÇÕES EM ASSEMBLY

```asm
.section .data

    .global string1Ptr

    .global string2Ptr

    .global string3Ptr


.section .text

    .global str_cat

str_cat:

    #prologue
    pushl %ebp                  #save previous stack frame pointer
    movl %esp, %ebp             #the stack frame pointer for sum function

    movl string1Ptr, %ebx   
    movl string2Ptr, %ecx
    movl string3Ptr, %eax       #String final

    str_loop1:
        cmpl $0, (%ebx)         #verifica se está no final da string
        jz end                  #jump se zero

        movb (%ebx), %dl        #guardar a letra        
        movb %dl, (%eax)

        incl %ebx
        incl %eax

        jmp str_loop1

    str_loop2:
        cmpl $0, (%ecx)
        jz end

        movb (%ecx), %dl
        movb %dl, (%eax)

        incl %ecx
        incl %eax

        jmp str_loop2


    end:
        #epilogue
        movl %ebp, %esp         #restore the previous satck pointer("clear" the stack)
        popl %ebp               #restore the previous stack frame pointer
        ret
```

O que é que pode estar errado?

Comment: Qual a questão que tem em concreto ? O código em C não reservou espaço na `string3` para o resultado da concatenação, logo deveria ser `char string3[7]`. E o código em assembly não colocou o terminador `0` na `string3`, assim como o termino do 1 loop é para o `end` e não para o 2 loop